# Flashing Root Page during navigation in MAUI Windows application when we do PopToRootAsync() and then PushAsync()

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, maui-windows

I am working on the MAUI windows application. I am facing an issue with the navigation. In some scenarios, I have to do PopToRootAsync() and then PushAsync() but **here the issue is that RootPage is flashing for fraction of a second, and then the new page is visible (which is pushed).**

Let's say there are 4 pages, Page1 -> Page2 -> Page3 -> Page4. Page 1 is my RootPage (Main Page). When I want to navigate from Page 4/3/2 to Page1, I simply do PopToRootAsync() but when I want to go from Page4 to Page2, I am doing PopToRootAsync() and then Push Page2. Another reason is I don't want to keep pushing Page in the navigation stack.

```
private async Task ToTestIOPage()
{
     await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(false); //animation is false

     TestIOVM vm = VM.Create<TestIOVM>();
     vm.SharedVM = SharedVM;
     await Navigation.Push<TestIOPage>(vm, false); //animation is false 
}
```

Suggest some alternatives or workaround.

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the `PopToRootAsync()` and `PushAsync()` methods (it shouldn't be `Push()`) right after one another? Maybe instantiate the ViewModel **before** making those calls. I don't know if the ViewModel does some heavy loading or whether the factory method creates a delay.

Comment: awaiting both PopToRootAsync() and PushAsync().

Comment: No, the suggestion is to re-order your code, so that the two "awaits" are sequential. Move  the first await down to immediately before the second await.

Comment: GoToAsync("/TestIOPage") should pop to the desired location. I would also use the community toolkit DI instead of a custom vm manager like you have. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0